# How to use await in a ternary operator in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await, conditional-operator

With this code the call to `SoftUpdateAsync` and `UpdateAsync` seems not awaited and I got an error of deadlock transaction.

```
_ = await _tabRepository.IsReferencedFromAnotherTableAsync(entity.Id)
    ? _tabRepository.SoftUpdateAsync(entity)
    : _tabRepository.UpdateAsync(entity);
```

The function `IsReferencedFromAnotherTableAsync` return a bool, the `UpdateAsync` and the `SoftUpdateAsync` returning a Task.

But, If I wrote the code as

```
if (await _tabRepository.IsReferencedFromAnotherTableAsync(entity.Id))
    await _tabRepository.SoftUpdateAsync(entity);
else
    await _tabRepository.UpdateAsync(entity);
```

all seems to work correctly.

Can I use ternary operator instead of if then else ?

I tried with:

```
_ = await _countdownRepository.IsReferencedFromAnotherTableAsync(entity.Id)
    ? await _countdownRepository.SoftUpdateAsync(entity)
    : await _countdownRepository.UpdateAsync(entity);
```

and

```
await _countdownRepository.IsReferencedFromAnotherTableAsync(entity.Id)
    ? await _countdownRepository.SoftUpdateAsync(entity)
    : await _countdownRepository.UpdateAsync(entity);
```

Both result in errors:

First one is "A value of type void may not be assigned", the second one is "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement "

Comment: *"both result in an error"* - What is the error?

Comment: First one is "A value of type void may not be assigned", the second one is 
"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement "

Comment: What does that have to do with a deadlock?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I strongly suspect you want:

```cs
await (await _countdownRepository.IsReferencedFromAnotherTableAsync(entity.Id)
    ? _countdownRepository.SoftUpdateAsync(entity)
    : _countdownRepository.UpdateAsync(entity));
```

Or to make it clearer what's going on:

```cs
var task = await _tabRepository.IsReferencedFromAnotherTableAsync(entity.Id)
    ? _tabRepository.SoftUpdateAsync(entity)
    : _tabRepository.UpdateAsync(entity);
await task;
```

I strongly suspect the problem is that `_tabRepository.SoftUpdateAsync(entity)` (and the other branch) both return just `Task` - which when you await it, doesn't return anything. You can't have a conditional ?: expression where the two branches don't return anything. So you need to determine which task you want to await, then await it - which is what my two options above do.

Comment: Yes, Update and SoftUpdate are both like `public async Task SoftUpdateAsync(Entity e)`

Comment: @rinomau: In future, it's really helpful to provide a [mcve] including any errors etc, so no-one has to guess.

Comment: sorry for that, sorry about that, I felt like a small example was too complex anyway ... so I try to write only essential code

Comment: @rinomau: The signatures of the methods you're calling *are* essential. Here's an example of what I'd have posted in your situation: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/cb8d280ae9be1d627ab19e8a10d31488

Comment: I thought I made this clear enough in writing "The function IsReferencedFromAnotherTableAsync return a bool, the UpdateAsync and the SoftUpdateAsync returning a Task." I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I'll add it to the question. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @rinomau: The problem is that if you'd written `Task<int>` (for example) but not bothered putting the backticks around, it would show up exactly as you've already written it. There's always less ambiguity when you *show* the code instead of *describing* the code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `SoftUpdateAsync` and `UpdateAsync` return `Task``and not just`Task`(which is equivalent to`void`), then you need to help the compiler with some extra parentheses to indicate precedence:

```
await _countdownRepository.IsReferencedFromAnotherTableAsync(entity.Id)
    ? (await _countdownRepository.SoftUpdateAsync(entity))
    : (await _countdownRepository.UpdateAsync(entity));
```

Alternatively you can assign and await the returned `Task` or `Task<T>`:

```
var updateTask = await _countdownRepository.IsReferencedFromAnotherTableAsync(entity.Id)
    ? _countdownRepository.SoftUpdateAsync(entity)
    : _countdownRepository.UpdateAsync(entity);

await updateTask;
```

which can be simplified to:

```
await (
await _countdownRepository.IsReferencedFromAnotherTableAsync(entity.Id)
    ? _countdownRepository.SoftUpdateAsync(entity)
    : _countdownRepository.UpdateAsync(entity)
);
```

Comment: I doubt that the first version will work, because I doubt that `await _countdownRepository.SoftUpdateAsync(entity)` returns anything. Using brackets won't help that.

Comment: Good point Jon - have updated - although I see your answer is basically identical so I'll probably end up deleting this one.

Comment: You were Skeeted!